# Python C-Api… how to create an "IntEnum" object from C

Tags: python, c, api

I want to create an *IntEnum* subclass called *MqHandShakeE* in **C** using  **Tcl-C-Code** from the example as template

```
int NS(Get_MqHandShakeE_FromObj) (Tcl_Interp *interp, Tcl_Obj *enumE, enum MqHandShakeE *ret) {
  int index;
  const static struct LookupEnumE keys[] = {
    { "START",                MQ_HANDSHAKE_START   },
    { "OK",                   MQ_HANDSHAKE_OK      },
    { "ERROR",                MQ_HANDSHAKE_ERROR   },
    { NULL,                   0                    }
  };
  TclErrorCheck (Tcl_GetIndexFromObjStruct (interp, enumE, &keys,
      sizeof(struct LookupClassS), "enum", TCL_EXACT, &index));
  *ret = keys[index].val;
  return TCL_OK;
}
```

my Goal is to call a python function with…

```
myfunc … MqHandShakeE.OK …
```

the C-constant `MQ_HANDSHAKE_START` is an **INTEGER**

Python only solution:

```
from enum import IntEnum
class WAIT(IntEnum):
  NO  = 0
  ONCE = 1
  FOREVER = 2
```

this is type-safe because `WAIT.NO` has type `WAIT` and value `0`… this i can check… the sub-module approach from down is **not** type-safe… the `WAIT.NO` as sub-module has type `int`

Comment: When I write Python wrappers for our C++ code, concerning `enum`s, I make a (sub-)module for each `enum` and then add `int` variables for the resp. enumerators. (Something like `enum` seems not to exist in Python.) May be, it would be possible to sub-class one of the built-in Python integer types but the module/variable trick does properly in our case. Hence, I never tried the sub-classing.

Comment: I test **submodul** approach… the problem is… it is **NOT** typesafe

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwisjpvBzuX2AhWWh_0HHeemB7kQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffossies.org%2Flinux%2Fsudo%2Fplugins%2Fpython%2Fsudo_python_module.c%3Fm%3Db&usg=AOvVaw3ltIkZAzO2zQlqWBIFwmkY) code as an excellent reference to implement Enum using python c-API.

```c
void register_enum(PyObject *py_module, const char *enum_name, PyObject *py_constants_dict) {
        PyObject *py_enum_class = NULL;
    {
        
        PyObject *py_enum_module = PyImport_ImportModule("enum");
        if (py_enum_module == NULL) {
            Py_CLEAR(py_constants_dict);
        }

        py_enum_class = PyObject_CallMethod(py_enum_module,
                "IntEnum", "sO", enum_name,
                py_constants_dict);

        Py_CLEAR(py_constants_dict);
        Py_CLEAR(py_enum_module);
    }

    if (py_enum_class && PyModule_AddObject(py_module, enum_name, py_enum_class) < 0) {
        Py_CLEAR(py_enum_class);
    }

}
```

To use the function above, call it the following:

```c
PyObject* py_constants_dict = PyDict_New(); // empty for the sake of example 
    PyDict_SetItemString(py_constants_dict, "test1",  PyLong_FromLong(1) );
    PyDict_SetItemString(py_constants_dict, "test2",  PyLong_FromLong(2) );
    register_enum (m , "TestEnum", py_constants_dict);
```

It is equivalent to this python code:

```py
import enum 
class TestEnum(enum.IntEnum):
   test1 = 1
   test2 = 2
```

Comment: This has helped my case for passing enum values to a function.

Answer (score 1):

After I had published a sample for C++, I realized that OP had tagged the question with C (not C++). Sorry, my fault. Here a sample in C:

```
#include <Python.h>

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* sample enum in C */
enum MQ_HANDSHAKE {
  MQ_HANDSHAKE_START,
  MQ_HANDSHAKE_OK,
  MQ_HANDSHAKE_ERROR
};

/* make Python binding for MQ_HANDSHAKE */

static struct PyModuleDef moduleMQ_HANDSHAKE = {
  PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
  "MQ_HANDSHAKE", /* name of module */
  NULL,           /* module documentation, may be NULL */
  -1,             /* size of per-interpreter state of the module,
                   * or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables.
                   */
  NULL            /* function table (no functions) */
};

static PyObject* initModuleMQ_HANDSHAKE(void)
{
  static PyObject *pSelf = NULL;
  if (!pSelf) {
    pSelf = PyModule_Create(&moduleMQ_HANDSHAKE);
    PyModule_AddObject(pSelf, "START", PyLong_FromLong(MQ_HANDSHAKE_START));
    PyModule_AddObject(pSelf, "OK", PyLong_FromLong(MQ_HANDSHAKE_OK));
    PyModule_AddObject(pSelf, "ERROR", PyLong_FromLong(MQ_HANDSHAKE_ERROR));
  }
  return pSelf;
}

/* adds module MQ_HANDSHAKE to Python modules table.
 */
void appendModuleMQ_HANDSHAKE(void)
{
  assert(!Py_IsInitialized());
  PyImport_AppendInittab("MQ_HANDSHAKE", &initModuleMQ_HANDSHAKE);
}

/* test program */
int main()
{
  /* initialize Python extension MQ_HANDSHAKE */
  appendModuleMQ_HANDSHAKE();
  /* initialize Python interpreter */
  Py_Initialize();
  /* sample Python program */
  static const char *const pyProgram
    = "print(\"Hello world (from Python).\")\n"
      "\n"
      "# import Python extension MQ_HANDSHAKE\n"
      "import MQ_HANDSHAKE\n"
      "\n"
      "# test whether it works\n"
      "def printHandshake(value):\n"
      "  if value == MQ_HANDSHAKE.START:\n"
      "    print(\"MQ_HANDSHAKE_START\")\n"
      "  elif value == MQ_HANDSHAKE.OK:\n"
      "    print(\"MQ_HANDSHAKE_OK\")\n"
      "  elif value == MQ_HANDSHAKE.ERROR:\n"
      "    print(\"MQ_HANDSHAKE_ERROR\")\n"
      "  else:\n"
      "    print(\"Illegal MQ_HANDSHAKE value!\")\n"
      "\n"
      "printHandshake(MQ_HANDSHAKE.START)\n"
      "printHandshake(MQ_HANDSHAKE.OK)\n"
      "printHandshake(MQ_HANDSHAKE.ERROR)\n"
      "printHandshake(0)\n"
      "printHandshake(1)\n"
      "printHandshake(2)\n"
      "printHandshake(42)\n";
  /* run Python interpreter */
  const int ret = PyRun_SimpleString(pyProgram);
  if (ret) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Execution in PyRun_SimpleString() failed!\n");
  }
  /* done */
  return ret;
}
```

Compiled and tested in VS2013 with Python 3.6:

```
Hello world (from Python).
MQ_HANDSHAKE_START
MQ_HANDSHAKE_OK
MQ_HANDSHAKE_ERROR
MQ_HANDSHAKE_START
MQ_HANDSHAKE_OK
MQ_HANDSHAKE_ERROR
Illegal MQ_HANDSHAKE value!
```

This sample establishs a module `MQ_HANDSHAKE` which
- has to be appended to the Python tables (using `PyImport_AppendInittab()`)
  before `PyInitialize()` has been called
- has to be imported in the Python code (using `import MQ_HANDSHAKE`).

---

The original answer with code in C++:

I took a look at our Python wrappers and made a little sample for OPs case:

```
#include <Python.h>

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

// sample enum in C/C++
enum MQ_HANDSHAKE {
  MQ_HANDSHAKE_START,
  MQ_HANDSHAKE_OK,
  MQ_HANDSHAKE_ERROR
};

namespace Py {

namespace MQ {

// make Python binding for MQ_HANDSHAKE

namespace HANDSHAKE {

static struct PyModuleDef module = {
  PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
  "mq.Handshake", // name of module
  nullptr,        // module documentation, may be NULL
  -1,             /* size of per-interpreter state of the module,
                   * or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables.
                   */
  nullptr         // function table (no functions)
};

static PyObject* init()
{
  static PyObject *pSelf = nullptr;
  if (!pSelf) {
    pSelf = PyModule_Create(&module);
    PyModule_AddObject(pSelf, "START", PyLong_FromLong(MQ_HANDSHAKE_START));
    PyModule_AddObject(pSelf, "OK", PyLong_FromLong(MQ_HANDSHAKE_OK));
    PyModule_AddObject(pSelf, "ERROR", PyLong_FromLong(MQ_HANDSHAKE_ERROR));
  }
  return pSelf;
}

} // namespace HANDSHAKE

// make module MQ

static struct PyModuleDef module = {
  PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
  "mq",     // name of module
  nullptr,  // module documentation, may be NULL
  -1,       /* size of per-interpreter state of the module,
             * or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables.
             */
  nullptr   // function table (no functions)
};

// initializes module mq
static PyObject* init()
{
  static PyObject *pSelf = nullptr;
  if (!pSelf) {
    pSelf = PyModule_Create(&module);
    PyModule_AddObject(pSelf, "Handshake", HANDSHAKE::init());

  }
  return pSelf;
}

// adds module mq to Python modules table.
void append()
{
  assert(!Py_IsInitialized());
  PyImport_AppendInittab("mq", &init);
}

} // namespace MQ

} // namespace Py

// test program
int main()
{
  // initialize Python extension mq
  Py::MQ::append();
  // initialize Python interpreter
  Py_Initialize();
  // sample Python program
  static const char *const pyProgram
    = "print(\"Hello world (from Python).\")\n"
      "\n"
      "# import Python extension mq\n"
      "import mq\n"
      "\n"
      "# test whether it works\n"
      "def printHandshake(value):\n"
      "  if value == mq.Handshake.START:\n"
      "    print(\"MQ_HANDSHAKE_START\")\n"
      "  elif value == mq.Handshake.OK:\n"
      "    print(\"MQ_HANDSHAKE_OK\")\n"
      "  elif value == mq.Handshake.ERROR:\n"
      "    print(\"MQ_HANDSHAKE_ERROR\")\n"
      "  else:\n"
      "    print(\"Illegal MQ_HANDSHAKE value!\")\n"
      "\n"
      "printHandshake(mq.Handshake.START)\n"
      "printHandshake(mq.Handshake.OK)\n"
      "printHandshake(mq.Handshake.ERROR)\n"
      "printHandshake(0)\n"
      "printHandshake(1)\n"
      "printHandshake(2)\n"
      "printHandshake(42)\n";
  // run Python interpreter
  const int ret = PyRun_SimpleString(pyProgram);
  if (ret) {
    std::cerr << "Execution in PyRun_SimpleString() failed!\n";
  }
  // done
  return ret;
}
```

Compiled and tested in VS2013 with Python 3.6:

```
Hello world (from Python).
MQ_HANDSHAKE_START
MQ_HANDSHAKE_OK
MQ_HANDSHAKE_ERROR
MQ_HANDSHAKE_START
MQ_HANDSHAKE_OK
MQ_HANDSHAKE_ERROR
Illegal MQ_HANDSHAKE value!
```

I must admit that I resembled this sample by cheating in our production code which we once did patiently while digging through the online resources. For a basic introduction, I recommend [1. Embedding Python in Another Application](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html).

The root module has to be imported in the Python code before it can be used (`import mq` in the Python sample code). In our productive code, we did it in a separate preceding call of `PyRun_SimpleString()`, so that our Python application programmers even don't need to care about this.

I splitted the implementation into multiple modules (`mq` and `mq.Handshake`). This surely could be done even shorter by establishing a module `mqHandshake` with the module variables `START`, `OK`, and `ERROR`.

Comment: @AndreasOtto I overlooked the C tag. However, it looks quite similar in C. I extended the answer with a C sample (implementing the mentioned alternative with only one module).

Comment: Hi, I tested this… using
> `PyModule_AddIntConstant(pSelf, "START", MQ_HANDSHAKE_START)`
the problem is… the module `const` has type `int` this is no improvement adding regular toplevel
> `PyModule_AddIntConstant(pSelf, "HANDSHAKE_START)",MQ_HANDSHAKE_START)`

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer… to create a **type-safe** *IntEnum* class in python-C-api.

→  [Python C-API… how to write python code in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429829/python-c-api-how-to-write-python-code-in-c/53437252#53437252)